# element with default enumeration value

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

Is it possible to set a default value for an element with type of enumeration?

I tried the following:

```
<xsd:element name="progressType" type="tns:progressType" default="Type A" nillable="false"/>
```

where `tns:progressType` is an enumeration:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="progressType">
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="Type A" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="Type B" />
   </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

However, when I'm instantiating any object which contains the `progressType` attribute `object.getProgressType()` is always null.

Comment: Yes, in XSD it is possible and you have done it correctly in your sample XSD. However you said `when I'm instantiating any object which contains the progressType attribute` , but in your example XSD `progressType` is an element, not an `xs:attribute`. Note that XSD only allows a default value in an attribute if the attribute use is optional, and the default value will be asigned if the attribute is not present. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using any `xsd:attribute` in my XSD because JAXB was able to generate the object I needed with `xsd:element`. What's the difference when it comes to object generation between `xsd:element` and `xsd:attribute`?

Comment: I am familiar with XSD but not with JAXB so I don't really know the difference in object geneartion.